# Post Routes Slim PHP

Tags: php, post, forum, slim

I am trying to create a forum for my website. I have been running into issues with posting data. I planned for it to be so that when the user clicks on a category, it POSTs the category's id so I can then get that id and then list all of the topics under that category id.

```
$app->get('/showTopic/category/:cat_id', function($cat_id) use($app) {

       echo $cat_id;

})->name('showTopic');


$app->post('/showTopic/category/:cat_id', function() use($app) {

       $cat_id = $app->request()->post('cat_id');

})->name('showTopic.post');
```

Now I am only echoing the `cat_id` because I want to get this working before I do any thing else.

```
<a href="{{urlFor('showTopic.post')}}">
```

This is my anchor tag for creating the link to the page that I will show the topic. However when I click on the link the page just displays `:cat_id` whereas is i were to manually change the url to a number it would display that number.

I know how to get the id for the category, I just want to test it with the number 1 for now.

So my big question is how do I pass that number in/what am I doing wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to render the template?

Comment: I am not rendering a template to test this, It just takes me to a blank page and displays the value of the cat_id, but I can't get that value to be a number, it just is displaying cat_id, unless I manually change the url

Comment: What I'm saying is, **I think I need more context**.  You are telling me that it just displays "cat_id", right?  So, where is the code that actually outputs that content?  Also, why are you using a `POST` route in the first place to generate content?

Comment: how else would i do that?

Comment: Using a `GET` route.  You want a user to be able to click on a category, which will take them to a page that contains a list of all the topics for that category, right?  You just need one `GET` route to handle that.

Comment: But how would the route be able to grab that specific category id without it being posted

Comment: Just as you've already done!  In your `$app->get(...` line, that is the route that grabs the category ID.  All you need then is a link to that.  For example, `<a href="/showTopic/category/1">Category 1</a>`

Comment: But how do I set that cat_id to the id of the category?

Comment: Can you put your code up on a Github repository or something?  At least one of us is very confused by what you're trying to do.  It might help to see the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you're asking, but it seems you want to create an url for the `showTopic.post` route . You can add additional parameters to the `urlFor` function and set the `cat_id` to 1:

```
<a href="{{urlFor('showTopic.post', {"cat_id": "1"})}}">
```